# Существует ли краткий справочник, годный для распечатки со всеми методами STL?

Tags: stl, c++

Существует ли краткий справочник, годный для распечатки со всеми методами STL классов и их кратким описанием? 
Не смог найти в интернете.

Comment: _Краткий_? Вряд ли.

Comment: Я тоже ни разу не видел (а хотелось бы (карманного формата)).

Answer (score 2):

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/369635/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-www-cplusplus-com) этот вопрос был освещен